# Unrecognized feature vr iframe allow

Tags: html, iframe, virtual-reality

I have an iframe as below in my website which is integrated with laravel.

```
<iframe allow="vr" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" src="<External-URL>">
```

vr mode not working properly. It shows an error in the console

```
Unrecognized feature: 'vr'.
```

Please help me to fix this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You must set `allowvr="yes"` on the iframe. If you go to https://aframe.io, you'll see that all the examples are iframed, so you can follow their example.

```
<iframe allowvr="yes" src="https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/boilerplate/hello-world/"></iframe>
```